# Complementing function using DeMorgan's Laws

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

The question states find the complement of the following expression:

x'y' + xy

i am not sure about my solution which is:

(x'+y') + xy

Comment: To complement, each $+$ will become a $\cdot$ and each $\cdot$ a $+$.

Comment: See [De Morgan Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: so when they ask me to complement a function F using DeMorgan i will need to make it F' for the whole function right?

Comment: "complementing" is *negation*. The negation of an expression $F$ is obtained putting the negation sign in front of the expression : $\lnot F$. Then use De Morgan to "move inside" the negation sign.

Comment: You should include the steps you took to reach the solution.  Then you could find where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align} (x'y'+xy)' & = (x'y')'  \cdot (xy)'. \\ & = (x+y) \cdot (x'+y'). \\ & = xx'+xy'+yx'+yy'. \\ & =xy'+yx'. \end{align}$$

Since $xx'=yy'=0.$

Comment: final answer could be simplified to xy' + yx' ?

Comment: Yeah it could be. I leave it to you.